# Sliding Panels with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slide

This example I've found is exactly what I was looking for:  [http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RZpbK/](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RZpbK/%20) 

Thx to the author [sg3s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893918/sg3s)

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
            animIn = function () {
                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    right: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            };

        if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: -$this.width()
                }, 500, animIn);
            });
        } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            animIn();
        }
    });

});
```

But I got a little problem with it. I would like the panels to "open" and "close" from the right. I'm not familiar with javascript and I'm not able to tweak it properly.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Sir, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `left: -($target.width())` with `left: $target.width()` in both places

Comment: It works at the beginning and then the panels act oddly... You can check it here http://troisssoleils.com/t&w/home.html

Comment: fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/RZpbK/860/ . There was a need to hide the element that went away before showing the new one

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/RZpbK/845/

All I did was modify the animIn to:

```
            animIn = function () {
            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: +($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        };
```

Comment: I've made a mistake copy-pasting :)

Comment: What you've made is almost good, it's just that I want this "open-close" effect. When you click on a link the active panel closes and the other opens.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous comment, this is more what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/RZpbK/847/

Just changed it so animIn executed right away instead of as a callback after the fadeout was done.

```
$this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: -$this.width()
            }, 500);
            animIn();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not the effect that I want. But we're almost there :) 
I want the panels to comes from the right and then when you clic on another link the current panel "closes" going back again to the right side and the new one also comes from the same right side. Like drawers. Exactly the same effect as the first jsfiddle but on the other side.